# In IDE NetBeans For Java Debugging

Tags: java, netbeans6.5

While using eclipse we have a short cut key <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>i</kbd> to get the selected object values in debug mode. But I am not able to find out any such short cut key in `NetBeans IDE`. If any body knows that how to know the selected object value in debug mode please help me,
Thanks

Comment: maybe changing the keymap to the "eclipse" setting would help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here we go : [NetBeans IDE 6.0 - 6.5 Keyboard Shortcuts](http://wiki.netbeans.org/KeymapProfileFor60)

And here are some other useful shortcuts  when debugging Java code in NetBeans

- <kbd>F8</kbd> Step over
- <kbd>F7</kbd> Step into
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd> Step out
- <kbd>F5</kbd> Continue
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F8</kbd> Toggle line breakpoint
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F8</kbd> Create a new breakpoint dialog window for more breakpoint options
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F9</kbd> Evaluate expression
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F7</kbd> Create a new watch
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F5</kbd> Debug main project